# How do I set up PhpStorm for CiviCRM development?

Tags: developer

I've acquired PhpStorm and I was wondering if there was any guidance on the best way to set it up for CiviCRM development. I saw there was a little information about [coding style setup](http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/IDE+Settings+to+Meet+Coding+Standards) but there are a few other aspects.

- I notice that .idea isn't excluded in CiviCRM's .gitignore by default?
- How can I configure PhpStorm to run the web tests?

With a comprehensive answer we might be able to create a more comprehensive docs page to help others get up and running.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your first question you can set up phpstorm to use another project directory rather than the .idea direcory in your civicrm root.

I usually have an install of Drupal with CiviCRM plus drupal modules plus extensions and only the extensions are link to git.

I am also curious on how to use web tests in php storm... Did not know it was possible...

Comment: Thanks Jaap, I've set up having the project files and the 'working' files in different places, thanks to some help from here as well: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-343#comment=27-799345

It should be possible to run the tests from directly within PhpStorm! It would probably be easier if I was working with buildkit on Unix...